# can i use OR in Shopify case

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

let say I have three products and made a case
I want to know if I can use OR instead of duplicating the content again

```
{% case shipping_method.title %}
  {% when 'packageA' || 'packageB' %}
     around 5000 lines
  {% when 'packageC' %}   

{% endcase %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but it must be a valid syntax. `||` is not a valid operator in liquid.

You have to use `or` instead so it becomes `{% when 'packageA' or 'packageB' %}`

Comment: okay it works have some issue though when I used OR for example if a or b  = c but what would happen is if a or b = c c